# How do you extend a method's return type in typescript, without re-declaring the method?

Tags: typescript

If I have the following code:

```
abstract class Base {
}

class Extended extends Base {
}

abstract class BaseService {
    protected static entity = Base

    public getEntity() {
        return (this.constructor as typeof BaseService).entity
    }
}

class ExtendedService extends BaseService {
    protected static entity = Extended
}

const entityClass = new ExtendedService().getEntity();
```

the const entityClass has a type of "typeof Base", even though it is actually the Extended class.  Is there a way that I can define getEntity in BaseService so that it's return type is determined by the static entity in the class that was used to create the service instance (in this case, ExtendedService, but also works with any other class that extends BaseService?

Comment: Yuck, you can get [something like what you want](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhBOBLYBDARgGwgYWAe3gB4AVAPigF4oAFRAYwGsSAaKBiEPAMyjIG4AUAPQBnYPBR1gUOhhQiRUAELzoAbwEBfIbPmKAogA9gEAHYATCOagRjZ84pUj1AqG5t2LV6vDxhKUABEABYQGBh4gYLawmhiElIycgrKqgDKCABu9C7uUADagXR4pvEArlIEgQC6AFywCMjoWLgEhKCQ3KnOGfDZdBCkgq7uYijA9DamE6ABThBCeWBlmJMA5hDA+tPIIAAUAJT1wMGIIvkA5MWl4hX48BfVl2YzII9QGnl58Jtl8KZQE5nAB013KlXgwJeuxGbm0MQEuhSRhMXnMvX60FsqIc3QgGJyH1hBSKJXB9xq9TgSFQmBw93a4AgXRR9isBIGQ2JYwmdCmrwCrLRWh0ZOk0NA2GSiiopggAHcoELLOisjlDsCNlsdqBDnwgA) but it's not particularly pretty.

Comment: If you were not using `static` properties, I'd just tell you to use [polymorphic `this`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types). But there's no [static polymorphic `this`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), and no [strong typing for `constructor`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), so you can't do that directly. If you simulate strong typing for `constructor`, turn `protected` into `public`, and squint, you can get your desired behavior.  Shall I write this as an answer, or do you need something else?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for the explanation!  I appreciate the help!  I'm also dealing with the case where I have a method returning an instance of the entity (not using an abstract class for the entity here), and I'm having trouble figuring that out.  I would expect to use InstanceType<this['constructor']['entity']>, but I get "Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<this["constructor"]["entity"]>'"

Comment: I think I'd need to see a [mcve] of that to advise; not sure if you want to edit that into the current question or create a new one.

Comment: Sure thing. [something like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=26&ssc=7&pln=26&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhBOBLYBDARgGwgYWAe3gB4AVAPigF4oAFRAYwGsSAaKBiEPAMyjIG4AUALoYUAZzFQAQuOgBvAQF8hI8ZICiAD2AQAdgBMI+qBG179kmWPkCodk2YNHq8PGEpQARAAsIGDHiegsoC6GLA8Ch0wFCqEtKyAMoIAG70NvZQANqedHi64fAArtEEngC6AFywCMjoWLgEhKCQ3AnWyfBpdBCkgrb24SjA9Ca6I6AeVhBCmWBFmKMA5hDA6uPIIACSBai6PQAUAJTVO0P7EMTgEM3eiGJZAOR5u8Wl8I-lT3oTIJ-kCkymXgqyK8F0UF0EAA7lBgHcxAA6F6FEr4eCIn6bY4DOzKELCUTxLQ6Jz6TrdaCmUkWdoQCnpKCA+w5FERNFlKo1JCoTA4dHNa5tEnmIwMnp9XFQIYjOhjX4eEVkpQqfLhBw0oweKGwpWGcmpdLHRErNYbUBnPaHI58IA)

Comment: [You need a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhBOBLYBDARgGwgYWAe3gB4AVAPigF4oAFRAYwGsSAaKBiEPAMyjIG4AUALoYUAZzFQAQuOgBvAQF8hI8ZICiAD2AQAdgBMI+qBG179kmWPkCodk2YNHq8PGEpQARAAsIGDHiegsoC6GLA8Ch0wFCqEtKyAMoIAG70NvZQANqedHi64fAArtEEngC6AFywCMjoWLgEhKCQ3AnWyfBpdBCkgrb24SjA9Ca6I6AeVhBCmWBFmKMA5hDA6uPIIACSBai6PQAUAJRQCpmZ8KtF8LpQuhAA7lDA3ohiAHR5u8Wl8O96ExAxyg4igOyG+wgxHAEGarzEWQA5F9CiV8PBEeUkQDNpi+gM7MoQsJRPEtDonPpOt1oKYKRZ2hBqelTgTsrl8qjfhVqnAkKhMDh0c0YW1yeYjMyevjMkMRnQxoCPOLKUoVJyYnSJcYqPcnirDFTUulju8VmsNqBwXtDkc+EA) since compiler can't verify; answer to come soon

Comment: I actually just landed on going with this["constructor"]["entity"]["prototype"] rather than InstanceType and that works pretty well.  It still has some trouble resolving the type when I use the method from another method in the extended class (ex: this.getEntityInstance()), which seems strange, but it shows as the correct type when used from the outside (ex: new ExtendedService().getEntityInstance()).  If I figure out the full solution, I'll post something here.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: [Another alternative](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=20&pln=16&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhBOBLYBDARgGwgYWAe3gB4AVAPigF4oAFRAYwGsSAaKBiEPAMyjIG4AUALoYUAZzFQAQuOgBvAQF8hI8ZICiAD2AQAdgBMI+qBG179kmWPkCodk2YNHq8PGEpQARAAsIGDHiegsoC6GLA8Ch0wFCqEtKyAMoIAG70EITqusDIIA46Bpay5Ar2UADannR4uuHwAK7RBJ4AugBcsAjI6Fi4BISgkNwJ1snwaXQQpIK29uEoOXQm2bkeVhBCZWD1mPRQAOYQwFk5oACStai6kwAUAJQdJ6ulZfbwR-XwulC6EADuUGA3kQYgAdNVLg0mvBQXpTiB7lBxFAnqBBGVlCFhKJ4loCoZ9GMJtBTPiiqNUulMo4CSVZnZKhC6o18PBWh04EhUJgcKyBuAIMM8eYjET0tN6VB5otlvCPMKnPolCoauF8iLjFRfgCFQSxbc7qDDscVudLihrhB7nwgA) using generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jcalz for the help in figuring this out. In the end, we came up with two solutions.  The first, provided by @jcalz, uses the polymorphic this type, ends up looking like the code below:

```js
type HeritableCtor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

class Base {
}

class Extended extends Base {
    extendedProp = "hello";
}

abstract class BaseService {
    ["constructor"]: HeritableCtor<typeof BaseService>;

    static entity = Base

    public getEntity(): this['constructor']['entity'] {
        return this.constructor.entity
    }

    public getEntityInstance(): InstanceType<this['constructor']['entity']> {
        return new this.constructor.entity() as InstanceType<this['constructor']['entity']>;
    }
}


class ExtendedService extends BaseService {
    ["constructor"]: HeritableCtor<typeof ExtendedService>;
    static entity = Extended
}

const extended = new ExtendedService().getEntityInstance();
```

And the second, which utilizes generic types:

```js
type HeritableCtor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

class Base {
}

class Extended extends Base {
    extendedProp = "hello";
}

abstract class BaseService<Entity extends Base> {
    ["constructor"]: HeritableCtor<typeof BaseService>;

    static entity = Base

    public getEntity(): Constructor<Entity> {
        return this.constructor.entity as Constructor<Entity>;
    }

    public getEntityInstance(): Entity {
        return new this.constructor.entity() as Entity;
    }
}


class ExtendedService extends BaseService<Extended> {
    ["constructor"]: HeritableCtor<typeof ExtendedService>;
    static entity = Extended
}

const extended = new ExtendedService().getEntityInstance();
```

As far as I can tell, both are valid, and it may come down to personal preference, although if you see a difference, please comment, as I would love to hear what it is.

Comment: Polymorphic `this` essentially *is* a generic type parameter that automatically gets narrowed in each subclass.  I'm pretty sure it's implemented that way.